# images are not loaded properly in django (something is redirecting the img url)

Tags: angularjs, django

http://192.241.153.25:8000

This is the site I built using angular js as the frontend, and Django rest framework as the backend.

for some reason the images that are attached to posts are not displayed,

same goes for profile pictures.

I have set up the right static and media folder.

```
        STATIC_URL = '/static/'


    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
        #'/var/www/static/',
    ]

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")

    MEDIA_URL = "/media_cdn/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")
```

I am not sure what is causing it, but all the images that are inserted by using "img" tag will be redirected to the url with # at the end of it.

So, if I want to load an img by img src="192.241.153.25:8000/media_cdn/profile/imac_1.jpg"

it will instead take me to 192.241.153.25:8000/media_cdn/profile/imac_1.jpg#/

if you go to the live site, you will see the img not being loaded in the very top left corner.

can you help me out? im not sure if it's django or angular js that's doing it.

request any source code if you need.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by editing the urls.py like this

urlpatterns = static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + [

hope it helps!